# What are the odds against throwing six at least one with a single die in three trials?

Tags: probability

How to solve this:
What is the probability of throwing a six at least one with a single die in three trials?

Comment: Looks like a multiple choice question from an assignment.
It's totally OK to ask for help, but you need to show that you tried to answer the question on your own before.

Comment: I think that the probability of the 3 events must be 3/18 = 1/6 because in one turn, the probability of getting a six is 1/6, so it should add up obviously.

Comment: Well, "obviously" isn't really what mathematics are about, is it ?
Have you understood Robert.Sie answer ? If yes, maybe you can use his result to deduce your answer ! If the probability of throwing no 6 is p, what is the probability of throwing at least one 6 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this kind of question, it's almost always easier to try and find the difference to 1.

Here, if you know the probability $p$ of throwing no 6, you can deduce that the probability of throwing at least one 6 is $1-p$.

With 1 trial, the probability of throwing anything but a 6 is $5/6$. With 2 trials, both of them can't be 6, so the probability is $5/6*5/6$.

You can easily generalize the problem with n trials. With 3, the final result is $1 - (5/6)*(5/6)*(5/6) = 91/216$.

Comment: There is no real difference between throwing 3 dices 1 time and throwing 3 times 1 dice in this problem. Still, I've edited my answer.

Comment: what exactly does "With 2 trials, both of them can't be 6" mean?

Comment: It's just to explain why there is a multiplication between the two 5/6 terms. We want **both** results to be different from 6, that is to say that the first result can't be 6 (hence the first 5/6 term), that the second result can't be 6 (hence the second 5/6 term), and that these 2 events must happen in a row (hence the multiplication).

Comment: In 1 trial, the probability of getting a six is 1/6, so shouldn't it be 1/6 in any number of trials? If not, why and how does the probability of an even increase with the number of trials?

Comment: @shauryagupta If you roll the die once and get six, $1/6$ is the obvious probability. If you have three rolls to get at least one six then your chances of getting a six must increase. This is equivalent to "a six on the first roll or a six on the second roll or a six on the third roll" which could include one six, two sixes or three sixes in three rolls. These possibilities can occur in $3\times25=75$, $3\times5=15$ and $1$ different ways respectively, which is another way to see 91 out of 216. Try rolling three dice at the same time and asking the probability of at least one six showing.

Answer (score 1):

Roll the die once. How many possibilities? $6$.
Roll the die a second time. You now have $6$ new possibilities which can occur after each of the first $6$. Thus in $2$ throws there are $36 = 6 \times 6$ possibilities.

Draw a table with the numbers $1$ to $6$ down the left side and $1$ to $6$ along the top. The table grid has $36$ points. Think of $(a, b)$ for each point, for example $(1, 6)$ or $(1, 2)$ and so on. Six ways for $a$ and six ways for $b$ means $36$ ways for (a, b).

Now apply this thinking to $(a, b, c)$ for rolling three times. Six ways for $c$ and $36$ ways for $(a, b)$ means $216$ ways for $(a, b, c)$.

You can get at least one six in a variety of ways, where in the following none of a, b or c is 6.

$(6, b, c)$, $(a, 6, c)$, $(a, b, 6)$, $(6, 6, c)$, $(6, b, 6)$, $(a, 6, 6)$, $(6, 6, 6)$.

But this is a lot of work. The complimentary event to at least one $6$ is to get no sixes, which means $(a, b, c)$ where none of $a, b$ or $c$ are $6$ and thus have five possibilities each. That's $5 \times 5 \times 5 = 125$ using the above argument with six possibilities here with five. So there are $125$ ways to roll a die three times and not get a six. This has a probability of $125/216$, so to get at least one six is the same as to not get no sixes and this has a probability of $1 - 125/216 = 91/216$.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with answer 2) 125/216, because throwing no six within three attemps is calculated as follows: $5/6 * 5/6*5/6 = 125/216$.

Comment: i just changed the question

Comment: why are there 218 combinations? Shouldn't there be a total of 18 possible outcomes?

Comment: there are six differnt outcomes for the first throw, six for the second and six for the thrid, so in total $6*6*6 = 216$.

Comment: I dont understand why?